# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a search function in my react app which will also highlight the item searched. The search works fine. Or it did anyway. With the introduction of highlighting, I've ran across a few problems but have been able to solve most. But now I receive this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')".

From what I've seen online, it appears when a prop is undefined and you're trying to use .toLowerCase()

However, my prop IS defined as its the same one I used for the search, and I never even tried to implement .toLowerCase(). So i'm completely confused as to why I'm receiving this error.

EDIT: I was asked to add more code...

This is App.tsx

```
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

                   
<div
  searchValue={filter}
  showSearchBarInFullMode={true}
  searchBarPlaceholder="Search"
  onSearchValueChange={(value) => {setFilter(value);}}
>


<div>

<div 
 selectedCollapsible={selectedCollapsible}
 onItemClick={selectLeftPaneItem}
 filter={filter} NOTE: THIS IS THE LINE THE ERROR DIRECTS ME TO
> 


<Nav 
...
 navFilter={filter}
/>
...
</div>

</div>
```

This is nav.tsx

```
interface NavProps {

    navFilter?:string,
    names: string[],
    pageSize: number;
}
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.navFilter!== undefined) {
            if(props.names.includes(props.navFilter)) {
                const range = pager(props.names, props.pageSize);
                let newPage = range.getPageNumberByName(props.navFilter);
                setStepperValue(newPage);
            }
            
            
        }
    }, [props.navFilter])
```

ANY help in figuring this out would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please post more or a link to a REPl so that we can see where the problem is.

Comment: More code. this does not help us

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your second component in a tertiary statement so that it only renders once the filter has been set:

```
{filter &&
<AlsoNotRelevant
   filter={filter} 
>
}}
```